# Problems in parsing

Tags: bash, parsing

I dont know much about bash.
I want to do command line parsing. The following is for ex a ping result. I just want to parse some part from the statistcs. lets say  just just rtt min. How to do that?

If some one can give me a link to some page how to understand this, that would be great too.. my google search have given me nothing. (Actually this topic is very new to me so most probably my keywords were not correct).

```
PING 192.168.3.181 (192.168.3.181) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.3.181: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.95 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.3.181: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=14.4 ms

--- 192.168.3.181 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.952/9.220/14.489/5.269 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe answer to tail, set tail params to get last line, and then use sed to extract value you need

Comment: how to set tail parameters to get last line.. thats what i am unable to do

Comment: add -1 parameter to it. And you can check what params do you need by typing man <command>, for example man tail